# Disable action on data-href onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tag like this

```
<a onlclick="return isExecute();" data-href="/otherPage">
```

How can I do to prevent redirect to `/otherPage` when `isExecute()` return false.

Comment: You have a typo `onlclick` correct this, also post your `isExecute()` code?

Comment: Why not redirect from `isExecute()` function only as you know the result there itself ?

Comment: Add `return false;` as last statement in `function isExecute`

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<a onlclick="return isExecute();" data-href="javascript:if(isExecute()){ return '/otherPage'; }">
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="return isExecute(event);" data-href="/otherPage">
```

Write `isExecute()` function like this.

```
function isExecute(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Your Code */

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can prevent the default action of the anchor by doing this

```
<a onlclick="redirect()" data-href="/otherPage">
```

then on a function

```
 function redirect(e) {          
            if(!isExecute()) {
              e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
```

or if your isExecute function is async then you can preventDefault at first and pass the data-href and if returns true then redirect